# How do I connect my telegram bot (telebot) to PostgreSQL url

Tags: python, database, postgresql, telegram-bot, telebot

I would like to learn how to connect my telegram bot to database url so that I store bot users, date of join and user information. Help me through that tutorial. How to connect a my telegram bot to PostgreSQL/database url.

#code

```
from telebot import*

from telebot.types import*

from telebot.apihelper import ApiTelegramException

bot = telebot.TeleBot("590----86:AAF9_DU9F_6----rvls26HgJMzHyJJpY")

CHAT_ID = '@pristbank' #replace your channel id

admin = 'https://t.mepristlegacy'
```

Answer (score 1):

To connect your Telegram bot to a PostgreSQL database, you can use the psycopg2 library. First, you need to install the library using pip:

```
pip install psycopg2
```

Then, you can use the following code to connect your bot to the database:

```
import psycopg2
from telebot import TeleBot
from telebot.types import Message
bot = TeleBot("590----86:AAF9_DU9F_6----rvls26HgJMzHyJJpY")
# Replace these with your own PostgreSQL credentials
DATABASE_URL = "postgres://user:password@host:port/dbname"
def connect_to_db():
    conn = psycopg2.connect(DATABASE_URL, sslmode='require')
    return conn
def insert_user_data(user_id, join_date, user_info):
    conn = connect_to_db()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    query = "INSERT INTO users (user_id, join_date, user_info) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
    cursor.execute(query, (user_id, join_date, user_info))
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def handle_start(message: Message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    join_date = message.date
    user_info = f"{message.from_user.first_name} {message.from_user.last_name}"
    insert_user_data(user_id, join_date, user_info)
    bot.reply_to(message, "User information has been stored in the database.")
bot.polling()
```

Replace DATABASE_URL with your own PostgreSQL credentials. The connect_to_db function is used to establish a connection to the PostgreSQL database, and insert_user_data function is used to insert user data into the users table.
When the user sends the /start command to your bot, the handle_start function is called, which extracts the user's data and stores it in the database using the insert_user_data function. Hope this helps :)

Comment: User can't use the start command more than one time. It says "already exists" and stops. Send me the code of CREATE table and if it exists, the bot recognizes and continue.